# Segue from tab bar viewController to ViewController not working correctly

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app in Xcode controlled by a Tab Bar View Controller and on the first View, I have a button that I want to Modally segue to a separate popup ViewController.  However, when I hit the button in the app, the tab bar turns white and the app becomes completely unresponsive.  As far as I can tell everything is setup correctly in the code and in the Main.storyboard.  I need to fix this issue!

I've tried adding a segue in the storyboard, and I've also tried setting up the segue in the attached swift file.  Neither work and provide the same result every time.

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsS51.png)
[What it looks like when the button is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INyGo.png)

Comment: Can you add some relevant images/code of what you have tried?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't letting me, not sure why